# Configuring Tomcat to Use SSL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ssl, https

My first question - isn't it possible to use https without using a Digital Certificate? 
My second question - I'm securing few pages within my web application. So added the following

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        ......
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        ......
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I tried running the app and the pages for which ssl is enabled doesn't load. So I went ahead with creating certificate. Added the following in server.xml?

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" 
       scheme="https" 
       secure="true" 
       keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.11-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.11\.keystore" 
       keystorePass="johneipe"
       clientAuth="optional" 
       sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Still I'm unable to access those pages nor https://localhost:8443.

Comment: It's not for public internet application. It's test.

Comment: Also I created the key `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -validity 100` and copied the .keystore file to the directory mentioned  above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your protocol to
`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"`

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Why? What are the differences between specifying org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol and http/1.1?

Comment: @Kevin, value 'HTTP/1.1' means that SSL implementation will be chosen by Tomcat. If APR is enabled then Tomcat prefer APR implementation. But atributes keystoreFiles, keystorePass are reserved for JSSE configuration. Value 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol' means that you want to use JSSE implementation, which is consistent with your configuration.

Answer (score 8):

What format of keystore are you using?  I believe the default in the Tomcat config is a JKS, but if you're using a PKCS#12 (.p12 or .pfx extension), you'll need to specify that.
Note the keystoreType="PKCS12".

```
<Connector port="1443"
           maxThreads="200"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/opt/companyName/tomcat.keystore"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystorePass="password"
           ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       />
```

Comment: i must be using the default setting. I didn't change any settings, as a matter of fact I don't know what it means..

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log files indicating what might be the problem?  Look in the log directory for catalina.err.